# Directories owned by my user have directories in them owned by someone else

Tags: linux, filesystems, fedora

On my school directory when I ls -l (running Fedora) I see that I have a ton of files and directories owned by me, but one specific directory is owned by someone else. I recall a few months ago I tried copying that directory to my own as it had 744 privileges by that user. For some reason that user owns the directory in my home directory with 700 privileges so I cannot delete the directory. My home directory has 700 privileges.

Anyone know why something like this could have happened and how I can prevent it form happening in the future? Also, how should I go about deleting these files in my home directory? If needed I can contact IT but I want to see if there is anything I can do without contacting them.

Yellow is my user, red is the foreign user

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two possible options IMHO:

1. Check the permissions of your `/home/YELLOW` folder, if it
   has `o+w`, or `g+w`, someone (the user
   listed as the owner of the directory) may have created it there.
2. `root` did it. It doesn't make much sense for you, so probably if he/she did, it was by mistake (for example, performing some backup-and-restore administration and so on).

Normally permission for deletion of things in unix filesytems are grabbed from
the parent folder, so, you need to have "write permission" in a folder
to create or remove files (unless there is [sticky bit](http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora15/man1/chmod.1.html) in action);
directories are just special type of files so the rules still applies.

If the directory is empty, a simple `rmdir p2Testing` or `rm -rf p2Testing` would be enough.  But, if the directory has files and
sub-directories, you won't have permissions to modify or delete them
(look at the `drwx------`), and only someone with more powers will be
able to do it for you (e.g. root, or the owner if he still have +w in
`/home/YELLOW`).